# Babel Javascript source file line number macro

Tags: javascript, babeljs, line-numbers

I am creating a logging subsystem for JavaScript client code and using babel to preprocess the ES2015 code. The only solutions I see for getting source file name and line numbers are based on getting the call stack from exception handling. I was wondering if Babel or any other preprocessor support (or should support) something line the old C preprocessor concepts of "__ LINE__ " and "__ FILE __"? If it existed I could write:

```
mylog( "some text", anObject, __FILE__ , __LINE__)
```

and babel would kindly provide

```
mylog( "some text", anObject, "mydir/myfile.js", 135)
```

in the post-processed file. I can imagine writing a perl script to do this before invoking babel but getting webpack, jspm, or mocha to pipe the source through two preprocessors might be more than I can figure out how to do.

Thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone bumping into this through google after so many years, here's the current solution:

The npm package [babel-plugin-transform-line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-line) will transform `__line` into the current source line number and the [babel-plugin-transform-dirname-filename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-dirname-filename) will transform `__filename` and `__dirname` into the current source filename and the directory it is in respectively.

So, with these plugins installed and babel configured to use them, you can do the following with the intended result:

```js
mylog("some text", anObject, __filename , __line)
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, No.

Babel will just compile your code to ES5 depending on the plugins and presets you have mentioned in `.babelrc`.